# Code is not executing when i am writing code outside of document.ready() in jquery?

Tags: jquery

My code is this,so when I am putting this code in my main JS file outside document.ready() it does not execute , I have tried putting alert as well but when I am putting this in document.ready() it is working ,what it is happening?

```
            var imageFile = $('img').attr('src');
        console.log(imageFile);
        var bgcolor = $('.man').css('background-color');
        console.log(bgcolor);
```

### Update (from comment):

"I am using the shortcut one.. "

```
$(function () {
    $('.text').click(function () {
        $('span').css({
            "background-color": 'red',
            "color": 'black'
        });
    });
    $('div.man').click(function () {
        $('p').css('color', 'blue');
        $('ul.nav .check .inner').css('background-color', 'green');
        $('ul.nav .check').css('font-size', '40px');
    });
    $('a[href^= "mailto"]').css('text-decoration', 'none');
    $('body >div> p').click(function () {
        $('p').prepend("<h2>yeah its working,prepend</h2>");
        $('p').append('<h2>yeah its working,append</h2>');
    });
});
```

Comment: And why would you write it outside document ready if it's not working? The elements probably aren't available.

Comment: I am just asking the reason what may be the issue or what is the reason behind this?
why it is happening? :/

Comment: Is this JS in the head of your HTML page? The HTML elements have to be already loaded when jQuery applies its magic. `$(document).ready()` assures they're loaded before the JS is executed

Comment: @Reeno no it is in the external js file which i have already mentioned above as main.js

Comment: But is main.js included in <head> or just before </body>?

Comment: You will also want to use the shorter jQuery shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){YOUR CODE HERE});` which is just `$(function(){YOUR CODE HERE});`

Comment: main.js is in head section just below the jquery.js ..
when i am writing my code in external js below the document.ready() and when i am getting output in console i get undefined :(

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie yeah man i am using the shortcut one..
$(function(){
 $('.text').click(function() {
  $('span').css({
  "background-color": 'red',
  "color": 'black'
  });
 });
 $('div.man').click(function() {
  $('p').css('color', 'blue');
  $('ul.nav .check .inner').css('background-color', 'green');
  $('ul.nav .check').css('font-size', '40px');
 });
 $('a[href^= "mailto"]').css('text-decoration', 'none');
 $('body >div> p').click(function() {
  $('p').prepend("<h2>yeah its working,prepend</h2>");
  $('p').append('<h2>yeah its working,append</h2>');
 });
});

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready` ensure that all `DOM` structure get loaded and then it executes code inside it. This way we will get all element (in your case image)  to do operation on it and hence it is working in your case.

But if you don't use `$(document).ready`, then it is not guaranteed that all DOM is ready and if you try to execute your jQuery then it may or may not find the desired html element on which you are executing operation.

Answer (score 1):

as documented in official site

> **Description: Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully
>   loaded.**
>
> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."
>   jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside
>   $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object
>   Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included
>   inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire
>   page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

for more information :-

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/